# How does Android Studio show Error of "Parcelable implementation needs CREATOR field"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parcelable, lint

I understand it is necessary to implement Parcelable.Creator in an implemented `Parcelable`'s class.

But I don't understand how did editor know that and showed an error if I didn't implement Parcelable.Creator interface.

> "This class implements parcelable but does not provide a CREATOR field"

Even it shows an error in Android Studio, I still could build the app successfully.

It seems that actually it was not a compile error but an reminder?

I was wondering to know which way it used to detect and remind programmers.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the [lint tool](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint), that prompts the warning. You can see the list of rules in `Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections -> Android -> Lint` menu.

[image]

You can also disable rules that you do not want to be run by lint.

Comment: @azizbekan. Thanks for the info and the screenshot !

Answer (score 1):

Android studio uses Lint to scan code and suggest improvements or changes.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html

Comment: Thanks for the info!